# Mongoose save with condition in one database call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to save/insert the request body to my mongodb using mongoose however there's a condition that Im only allowed to save if the fields is **existing and with a field value of 'free'**.

What I tried so far is to get that record and then make a condition then save if condition is met. however is there a work around in mongoose to reduce this to one database call only for efficiency?

this is my current code:

```
let item = item.find({userId: req.body.userId);
if(item.status == 'free') myItem.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user update one where user id exists and status is equal to free , if not exists and status not equal free no documents will be updated.

If You want to retrieve item data you can replace `updateOne` with `findOneAndUpdate`

```
model.updateOne({ userId: req.body.userId ,status: 'free' },
                  itemData , 
                 { runValidators: true }, function(err, res) {

               });
```

Please replace itemData with the new item data ;